# Get function names for given stack trace

Tags: linux, debugging, gcc, stack-trace

Our application produces stack traces where some addresses aren't resolved to symbols.

At the moment there is no way to change the code that produces stack traces.

In particular there are no symbols from static library linked into the app. This static library is built with `gcc -g1 -O0`. I also tried `-g3`, but it produced unacceptably large static library and didn't work anyway. Our app uses C and C++ and builds with clang.

For addresses from that library I can obtain source file name and line number with `addr2line -e <app-name>` (how to obtain symbol name?).

Also I see symbols from the library (they are all non-extern, we need them this way) with `nm --defined-only <app-name>`.

Once app crashed and there are stack traces available I'm looking to "symbolize" those stack traces using information from the executable (app). How would I do it?

Comment: When I've done this is the past, I have a [perl] script that takes the stack trace data (from a saved file) and does `nm` [or `readelf -s`] from the executable and scans the stack trace data looking for address range matches. I helped things along in the app by doing `printf` with `<<%p>>` to delineate which hex values are of interest [but this isn't strictly required]. You may also need to read in `/proc/<pid>maps` to find base loading addresses and combine this with the `nm` data [and/or disable ASLR]. I'd use `readelf -s` instead of `nm` because it tends to work even if exe is stripped.

Comment: Thank you @CraigEstey It sounds like a working solution. `readelf -s` is nice.